# Interactive US Map with Altair: Linking States Upon Click

Tags: python, dataframe, geojson, altair

I am currently facing a challenge in data visualization, specifically in creating an interactive map using Python's Altair library. My project involves a map of the United States, where I want to implement a unique feature: upon clicking on any state (referred to as State_x in my dataset), the map should dynamically link to other states (referred to as State_y). This linkage is based on data points I have, which include the latitude and longitude of each state, and a certain 'count' metric that quantifies some relationship between these states.

Here is an example of my data frame:

| State_x | x_latitude | x_longitude | State_y | y_latitude | y_longitude | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | 32.31823 | -86.90229 | Alaska | 66.160507 | -153.369141 | 6 |
| Alabama | 32.31823 | -86.90229 | Arizona | 34.048927 | -111.093735 | 106 |

I am encountering a technical hurdle. When I create a choropleth map to represent this data visually, the map does not function as intended. Specifically, when I click on a state, the map should aggregate and display the total 'count' value related to all its links (State_y). But currently, it only shows the count of the first link.

This issue is critical for my project, as the interactive feature of the map is central to the user experience I aim to provide. The map should allow users to explore complex relationships between states easily and intuitively. The dataset is quite extensive, with each of the 50 states linked to 50 others, creating a significant volume of data to be represented accurately and interactively on the map.

I am seeking advice and solutions on how to overcome this issue, ensuring that the map correctly aggregates and displays the data upon user interaction. Any guidance on how to leverage Altair or other Python tools to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Load GeoJSON data for the map
with open('gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json') as f:
    geojson_data = json.load(f)

# Create an interactive selection based on the 'State_x' field
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['State_x'])

# Base chart for the states with choropleth encoding
base = alt.Chart(alt.Data(values=geojson_data['features'])).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color='count:Q',  # Set the color based on the count
    tooltip=['properties.NAME:N', 'count:Q']
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='properties.NAME',
    from_=alt.LookupData(final, 'State_x', ['count'])
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
).add_selection(
    selection
)

# Line chart for connections, visible only for the selected x state
lines = alt.Chart(df).mark_rule().encode(
    longitude='x_longitude:Q',
    latitude='x_latitude:Q',
    longitude2='y_longitude:Q',
    latitude2='y_latitude:Q'
).transform_filter(
    selection  # Filter lines based on the selection
)

# Layer the charts
panopticon_map = base + lines

# Display the chart
panopticon_map
```

This code gives me a choropleth plot, but based on first count for every state and not sum of all possible counts for that state. It shows all possible lines on the map, when I try to click on a certain point in map, it doesn't show any line at all.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, If you can share some toy data that can be used to reproduce the issue you're having, it is more likely that someone will be able to help you.